# JavaScript/Greasemonkey: Avoiding FireFox Security Warning when Submitting a Form from a Secure Page

Tags: javascript, firefox, forms, ssl, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script to connect two company-internal webpages.  One is SSL, and the other is insecure and can only be accessed via a POST request.  If I create a hidden form on the secure page and submit it via an `onclick()` in an `<a>`, it works fine, but FF gives a warning:

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

The insecure page can't be accessed via SSL and the other one can't be accessed w/o it, and I can't modify either server =\  Is there any way to avoid this warning by doing some kind of JavaScript/Greasemonkey redirect magic?  Thanks!

EDIT: The warning can't be disabled (for rather good reasons, since it's hard to tell if what you're about to send is secure, otherwise).  I'm mostly wondering if there's a way to POST in JavaScript without looking like you're submitting a form.

Comment: Writing GreaseMonkey script for corporate purposes? That's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This may be possible by doing a GM_xmlhttpRequest. e.g.,

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://your.insecure.site.here',
  onload: function(details) {

      // look in the JavaScript console 
      GM_log(details.responseText);

      /* This function will be called when the page (url) 
      has been loaded. Do whatever you need to do with the remote page here.*/
  }
});
```

API/more info here: [GM_xmlhttpRequest wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a new SSL site as a proxy that just passes data back to the insecure site. Or just have all your users turn off that particular security warning. (Sorry FF team, but that's not a terribly useful message to start with.)

Answer (score 0):

That's a browser configuration setting, which can't (or shouldn't) be changable by Javascript.

Unless the script needs to be used by more than one user, Tools -> Options -> Security.  You can click on settings to display which warning messages are displayed.  Note that this currently affects all sites rather then just your internal system.